# How to configure Selenium Node to run specified OS version?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

This is more of a question, can we configure selenium node to run specified OS version. I have a scenario where I need to run some Test in Windows 7 and some in Windows Server 2008 so I don't know if that's possible and if it is possible how to configure it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like 2 nodes under same hub, with one from win7 and another from server 2008?

Comment: @A.J No, i am able to do that. My question is can i choose which node my test to run on.

Comment: you can make use of the DesiredCapabilities.Platform capability to choose the node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own Capabilities by creating a Custom Capability Matcher and implement it to the Grid.

Or there is another and easier solution :) You work with the `applicationName` capability and use it to define the name of the node. It is an exist capability, but not documented *(I don't know why)*.

**In your nodeConfig:**

```
{
    "capabilities":[
        {
            "platform":"WINDOWS",
            "browserName":"internet explorer",
            "maxInstances":1,
            "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver",
            "applicationName":"PC001"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

**... and in your code:**

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
// ...
dc.setCapability("applicationName", "PC001");
```